# Best way to replicate logical operations using standard definitions

Tags: functions, logic, nonstandard-analysis

I want to replicate logical operations using standard function definitions. I found that the logical operation

```
def g(x):
  if x == d:
    return a
  else:
    return b
```

can evaluate to:

$$g(x) = \left|\frac{|x^2-2dx+d^2-\epsilon^2|}{x^2-2dx+d^2-\epsilon^2}-1\right|*\frac{a-b}{2}+b$$
*given $\epsilon$ is an infinitesimally small number.

This epsilon is the reason why my function above fails at using concepts only of standard function definitions. Is there a way to recreate these logical operations without resorting to such?

Comment: I don't really understand your proposed "infinitesimal-based" function (maybe you want to replace the final "$b$" by "$a+b\over 2$"?), but here's a quick negative observation: the desired $g$ is **discontinuous** (assuming $a$ and $b$ are distinct) but defined everywhere, so it cannot be defined in too simple a manner.

Comment: i used an infinitesimally based approach because if i subtracted instead by a real number it would evaluate to "a" for a given range of numbers. (e.g, 5, 5.0001, and 4.9999 would evaluate "a"). because i only want to test for equality to 5, i have to test a single number in an infinite amount of numbers, explaining the infinitely small point

Comment: $$g(x) = \begin{cases}a,&x = d\\b,&x \ne d\end{cases}$$ is the way mathematicians would normally define it. But before anyone can truly answer your question, we have to know what you consider "standard function definitions". For instance, do you consider $f(x) = |x|$ to be a standard function? Even though it itself is defined by $$|x| = \begin{cases}x,& x \ge 0\\-x,&x < 0\end{cases}?$$ What other operations do you consider "standard"?